# Excel to Ms Project VBA - Insert task, set font, underline and Italics

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have the following lines of code in VBA (Excel), successfully generating tasks in MS Project, with the correct outline level established. However, I would like to set the formatting of the 'Name field' of a specific task to be have an underline AND OR be italicized:

Sample Code:

```
ActiveProject.Tasks.Add ("Enter Task Name #1")
ActiveProject.Tasks ("Enter Task Name #1").OutlineLevel = 1
ActiveProject.Tasks.Add ("Enter Task Name #2")
ActiveProject.Tasks ("Enter Task Name #2").OutlineLevel = 2
ActiveProject.Tasks.Add ("Enter Task Name #3")
ActiveProject.Tasks ("Enter Task Name #3").OutlineLevel = 3
```

How would I go about setting formatting options to a task that is being imported **or** selecting the imported task and setting the required formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the tasks are entered, use the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.find) method to select the task and the apply formatting such as [FontBold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fontbold). For example:

```
Application.Find "Name", "equals", "Enter Task Name #2"
Application.FontBold
Application.FontItalic
```

Alternatively, use [FontEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fontex) which can be used to apply multiple formats at once.

Comment: Thank you Rachel. The Application.Find and Application.FontBold worked a treat. I received an error on the FontEx Approach, though suspect it was me not entering something correctly